# How can I share my desktop using Skype?

Tags: 10.04, skype, remote-access

I'm running Ubuntu Lucid Netbook Remix on my laptop and I need to be able to share my desktop for a Skype call. Does anyone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are in a video call, you can share your desktop by click on the video button (as in the picture) then click share your screen>choose what to share.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

With the latest version of Skype for Ubuntu, sharing your screen is activated differently.

You can either:

In a call: hit the + button in the call window > Share screens

Or...

Right click on a contact name > Share your screen... > Share full screen or Share selection

Answer (score 1):

With Skype 4.3.0.37 I have found that you - apart from finding the right menu item in Skype - also need to be on a connection with sufficient speed. Otherwise transmission will be very slow or freezes, as if congestion occurs.

When I was on my private fairly low-speed ASDL connection screen sharing did not work, but when I switched to a fast university connection there was no problem with Skype screen sharing from my Ubuntu Linux to a Windows computer.